# systemd service on CentOS

Tags: systemd

I have python code as a binary file.

This binary is placed in /bin/test_service

Also i have a service, for example test_service:

```
[Unit]
Description=TestService
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'umask 022; pgrep test_service > /run/test_service.pid'
PIDFile=/run/test_service.pid
OOMScoreAdjust=-100
ExecStart=/bin/test_service --start   
KillMode=control-group

Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To run this service i do:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable test_service
systemctl start test_service
```

But an error occurs:
(sudo journalctl -xe)

```
centos test_service[4234]: [4235] Failed to execute script 
centos test_service[4234]: Traceback (most recent call last):
centos test_service[4234]: File "test_service/run.py", line 21, in main
centos test_service[4234]: File "test_service/run.py", line 61, in create_app_directory
centos test_service[4234]: File "os.py", line 220, in makedirs
centos test_service[4234]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/test_service/'
```

There is a line to check what user runs script in the beginning of my python code. After that i try to create some files and folders, one of them is /opt/test_service/:

```
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    raise Exception("failed: should be root")

os.makedir("/opt/test_service/")
```

As a result i have got the error:

```
Permission denied: '/opt/test_service/'
```

On contrary, when i run next command everything is fine:

```
/bin/sudo /bin/test_service --start
```

And the same service works fine under Ubuntu/Debian/SUSE...

Could you, please help me to solve this problem?

As i understand the service runs with root permissions and the binary file also should be executed with root permissions, but something is going wrong...

Recently i have tested this service under CentOS 7 and everything was fine but with CentOS 8.1 i have got the problem.

Comment: I wonder if SELinux is preventing the systemd- version of the service from creating the directory while allowing your terminal- version of the service to do so. It's a little unnatural for a service to be creating directories in /opt; have you considered creating that/those directories during the installation process?

Comment: Just for an experiment i have changed the directory from /opt/test_service to /tmp/test_service. The service started. But... The problem still was there. I could not make any operation which need root permission. The problem is not in the service itself but in SELINUX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the end an answer have been found. I'm not sure if this is the best decision but my problem has gone away.

I have edited the file:

```
 /etc/selinux/config
```

From:

```
 SELINUX=enforcing
```

To:

```
 SELINUX=disabled
```

Restart the server (CentOS 8.1)

As @annahri has mentioned this way is not appropriate.

To run my service with right permissions i have changed the context of some files and folders to satisfy SELinux:

```
chcon -R system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 /bin/test_service
chcon -R system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 /opt/test_service
```

Comment: Disabling selinux is like unplugging the power cord to shutdown a machine.

Comment: @annahri could you propose a better idea?

Comment: I'm not a selinux expert, but I suggest you to investigate `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or simply `ausearch -m avc` as root. If you want human-readable version of what , pipe it to ` ... | audit2why` then it will tell you what causes selinux to deny your thing.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try